# Deserializing some JSON properties to a child object with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have this string in JSON format:

```
{
    "hr": "12:56",
    "vs": [
        {
            "pre": "73833",
            "a": true,
            "posx": "-46.688962875",
            "posy": "-23.632046625"
        },
        {
            "pre": "73722",
            "a": true,
            "posx": "-46.773388125",
            "posy": "-23.68939025"
        }                               
    ]
}
```

I want to deserialize the JSON to this class:

```
public class Tracking
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "hr")]
    public string Hour { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "vs")]
    public IList<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}
```

The `Vehicle` class currently has the following attributes:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    [JsonProperty (PropertyName = "pre")]
    public string Prefix {get; set; }

    [JsonProperty (PropertyName = "posx")]
    public string Y {get; set; }

    [JsonProperty (PropertyName = "posy")]
    public string X {get; set; }
}
```

Instead, I would like to deserialize the `posx` and `posy` attributes into a child class called `Position` with `X` and `Y` properties:

```
public class Position
{
    [JsonProperty (PropertyName = "posx")]
    public string Y {get; set; }

    [JsonProperty (PropertyName = "posy")]
    public string X {get; set; }
}
```

Resulting in the following `Vehicle` class:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    [JsonProperty (PropertyName = "pre")]
    public string Prefix {get; set; }

    public Position Position {get; set; }
}
```

I intend to use the `Position` class on more places on my system and would not like to repeat these properties. But when deserializing with the new structure, the `Position` property returns null.

```
{
    "hr": "13:08",
    "vs": [
        {
            "pre": "73833",
            "a": true,
            "Position": null
        },
        {
            "pre": "73722",
            "a": true,
            "Position": null
        }    
    ]
}
```

What can I do to make this code work?

Comment: Deserializing what? I think we need to see how is the json that you want to deserialize

Comment: updated question

Comment: You should separate the serialization part from the rest of your program. Make an adapter if you want to change the object hierarchy, otherwise you'll soon be struggling with hacks upon hacks to get the wanted json format. Better to separate the two.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can achieve the result you want.
The quickest way is to make a couple of changes to your original `Vehicle` class:

1. Add a new `Position` property and mark it with `[JsonIgnore]`
2. Make the `X` and `Y` properties private and change them so that they write to, and read from, the `Position` object.

The resulting class should look like this:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "pre")]
    public string Prefix { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Position Position { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "posx")]
    private string Y
    {
        get { return Position != null ? Position.Y : null; }
        set
        {
            if (Position == null) { Position = new Position(); }
            Position.Y = value;
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "posy")]
    private string X
    {
        get { return Position != null ? Position.X : null; }
        set
        {
            if (Position == null) { Position = new Position(); }
            Position.X = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5zT5Rf

---

If you don't like that idea, another option is to make a custom `JsonConverter` for your `Vehicle` class:

```
class VehicleConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Vehicle);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        Vehicle veh = new Vehicle();
        serializer.Populate(obj.CreateReader(), veh);
        Position pos = new Position();
        serializer.Populate(obj.CreateReader(), pos);
        veh.Position = pos;
        return veh;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Vehicle veh = (Vehicle)value;
        JObject obj = JObject.FromObject(veh.Position, serializer);
        obj.AddFirst(new JProperty("pre", veh.Prefix));
        obj.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

Then, mark your `Vehicle` class with a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to tie it to the converter:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(VehicleConverter))]
public class Vehicle
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "pre")]
    public string Prefix { get; set; }

    public Position Position { get; set; }
}
```

Demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HRSRa9

Answer (score 0):

If you use Newtonsoft you should be able to deserialize using `Vehicle myVehicle = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Vechicle)(myString)` given that:

- You are using the class at the bottom of your post.
- You are deserializing Json serialized from that class. If you have older Json from your previous Vehicle class that won't work, unless you handle that case specifically (if first deserialization fails try the old class, if that succeds convert it to the new Vehicle class.

Comment: Your Json does not seem to match your Vehicle class. The `JsonProperty` needs to match the names in your Json string. "p" => "pre", "px" => "posx" and so on...

Comment: You json still does not match your class(es). If you're having problems with the data structure try using https://app.quicktype.io/